# Integration over hexagonal unit cell

Tags: solid-state-physics, fourier-transform

I want to perform the integral $\sum_G\int d^2x e^{i G\cdot x}$ over a 2D hexagonal unit cell, where $G$ is the reciprocal lattice vector. I find it hard since the integration domain is hexagonal. Can this be done?

Comment: Don't know the answer, just wanted to ask,- should't it be a double-integration because there is a second derivative ? Like : $$ \int dx \int dx e^{i G\cdot x} $$. Also i'm not sure if sum is needed if there will be double-integration, because second integration will act as a sum operator.

Comment: Ahh, no the notation is $d^2x=dxdy$ and $e^{i G\cdot x}=e^{i(G_x x+ G_y y)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use coordinate system with grid parallel to two hexagon sides (let coordinates of two vertices be $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$):

[image]

$$
\int_{\text{hex}}f(x,y)dxdy = \frac{A_{\text{hex}}}3\int_{\text{hex}}\tilde f(u,v)dudv.
$$

then the domain of integration is the square $(0,0)-(2,2)$ minus two triangles $(1,0)-(2,0)-(2,1)$ and $(0,1)-(0,2)-(1,2)$

Comment: Thank you very much!